# Azure Python sdk - walk_blobs return container encoded

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-python-sdk

I'm trying to run a code similar to this one:

```
for blob in container_client.walk_blobs(delimiter='/'):
    print(blob)
```

for a container called "$mycontainer".
The request succeeds and I get the information. Howevert, for the property *container* of *blob*, the string returning is "%24mycontainer", and not "$mycontainer".
Seems like it's being encoded in some way.
Is there a way to have this property return the correct container name without encoding special characters?

Comment: %24 is the equivalent of the character $ in url encoding. Refer to here - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP. What is the issue you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

> The property *container* of *blob*, the string returning is "%24mycontainer", and not "$mycontainer".

I agree with Anand's comment **`%24`** is the equivalent of the character **`$`** in URL encoding.

If you need to get the **`$mycontainer`** unencoded container name, you can use the `unquote` function from the `urllib.parse` module in Python.

**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from urllib.parse import unquote

connection_string = "your-Connection-string"
container_name = "$sample"

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)

for blob in container_client.walk_blobs(delimiter='/'):
    container_name = unquote(blob.container)
    print(container_name)
```

**Output:**
This should print the container name as **`$sample`** instead of **`%24sample`**.

[image]

**Reference:**

[urllib.parse — Parse URLs into components — Python 3.11.6 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#url-quoting)